# ValueError: 'session' argument must be a ClientSession or None

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

What am I doing wrong here, I've connected to my DB and all seems to work good but when I use aggregation I get this error below:

```
Database(MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True), 'gym')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ibtissam\Desktop\pymongo\main.py", line 17, in <module>
    sportifsCouple =  myCollection.aggregate(
  File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 2435, in aggregate

    with self.__database.client._tmp_session(session, close=False) as s:
  File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1752, in _tmp_session

    raise ValueError("'session' argument must be a ClientSession or None.")
ValueError: 'session' argument must be a ClientSession or None.
```

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = client["gym"]
print(db)

pipeline = [
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$Age",
            "sportifs": {"$push": {"fullName": {"$concat": ["$Prenom", " ", "$Nom"]}}},
        }
    }
]

projection = {"$project": {"Age": "$_id", "ListOfSportifs": "$sportifs", "_id": 0}}

myCollection = db["Sportifs"]
sportifsCouple = myCollection.aggregate(pipeline, projection)


for sportif in sportifsCouple:
    print(sportif)
```

Comment: Aggregation has only one pipeline, but it can have as many stages as you want.  The projection needs to be done within the aggregation pipeline.  I don't recommend this style of coding, but does `sportifsCouple = myCollection.aggregate(pipeline.append(projection))` give the results you want?